# Problem with deep linking when published with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

can you please give me a hand with Deep Linking. When I work in a development environment it works for me with the URL: exp://192.168.100.4:19000/--/resetPassword/rzBsP3tJ, however, when I publish it, I open it with the URL: exp://exp.host/@user/@nameApp/--/resetPassword/rzBsP3tJ?release-channel=testing, it just opens the app, but it doesn't redirect me to the screen I want. What I can do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70097940/edit) your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This article here helped me to figure out some missing configurations, also, don't forget to add the  ```Linking.addEventListener``` -> https://javascript.plainenglish.io/easy-deep-linking-with-react-native-and-expo-84e3c7b9d63e

Answer (score 1):

An assumption here: you talk about screens so assuming you are using react-navigation and making use of LinkingOptions.

The issue is caused by a mismatch between how Expo defines a linking URL and how react-navigation defines LinkingOptions. LinkingOptions is in terms of a path, not a URL that has any query params. In development there are no query params, but an app that is is published to a channel has the 'release-channel' query param so this will never match in react-navigation's LinkingOptions.

The solution is just to remove the release-channel query param from the URL returned by `Linking.createURL`:

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { URL } from 'react-native-url-polyfill';


const urlWithReleaseChannel = Linking.createURL('/')
const parsedUrl = new URL(urlWithReleaseChannel)
parsedUrl.searchParams.delete("release-channel")

export const resetLinkingOptions = {
    prefixes: [parsedUrl.toString()],
    config: {
        screens: {
            ResetPassword: {
                path: 'resetPassword/:id'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for both development and deployed apps: if present, `release-channel` then behaves as a regular query param. Note that `react-native-url-polyfill` is required as a project dependency as out of the box the RN URL is not fully featured and lacks in this case the ability to delete a query param.